# Why does is.na() return TRUE on the first element of an empty vector in R?

Tags: r, vector, na, is-empty

So I was requested to write a function that returns a vector (specifically a character vector).
When the vector is NA I should print something.
When I check a vector that I know is empty:

```
is.na(foo)
```

I get -

```
logical(0)
```

but when I check:

```
is.na(foo[1])
```

I get

```
TRUE
```

Why is that?

**Edit** -

Was asked what is my source of `foo`:

It's from that function `filter` from the library `dplyr`

```
state_name_vec <- filter(uscities, city == city_name)$state_name
```

I can get a character vector, a character (i.e. a string in other languages) or, I guess, an empty character vector. I presume I can also get a data.frame, but in my case, I don't.

I have tried to understand what does the type `.data` mean, which filter returns.

[image: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter.html#:~:text=The%20filter()%20function%20is,%2C%20unlike%20base%20subsetting%20with%20%5B%20.]

After googling, I got this:

[image: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html]

So I guess my question is what happens when `.data` is empty?

Comment: How are you defining `foo` , like `foo <- character()` or ?

Comment: `?'['` says that subsetting with `NA` e.g. `foo[NA]`, "picks an unknown element and so returns `NA`". Indexing by a non-existing integer index is not mentioned, but I guess the logic for what gets returned is the same. If you use `[`to "pick an unknown element", `NA` is returned.

Answer (score 1):

If `foo` is `NULL`, then it would return `logical(0)` in both cases `foo[1]` is `NULL`

```
foo <- c()
foo[1]
#NULL
is.na(foo)
#logical(0)
is.na(foo[1])
#logical(0)
```

According to `?NULL`

> NULL can be indexed (see Extract) in just about any syntactically legal way: whether it makes sense or not, the result is always NULL. Objects with value NULL can be changed by replacement operators and will be coerced to the type of the right-hand side.

---

However, if the object created is one of the below (as mentioned in the comments)

```
foo <- character()
foo <- numeric()
foo <- integer()
```

the `length` of the vector is 0 and is not NULL.  So, if we try to extract values by specifying index, it gets filled by the corresponding `NA`.  Based on the `?Extract`

> When extracting, a numerical, logical or character NA index picks an unknown element and so returns NA in the corresponding element of a logical, integer, numeric, complex or character result, and NULL for a list. (It returns 00 for a raw result.)

```
foo[1]
#[1] NA
foo[1:3]
#[1] NA NA NA
foo[4]
#[1] NA
```